# Changing lines and polygons look on Google Map API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, polygons

I want to make something like this: http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/googletool.html
But I want to change the lines and give them a stroke of a color I choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color and the thickness of the lines are defined by the <LineStyle> node in the resulting KML file. You can easily change them.

```
<LineStyle><color>660000FF</color><width>0.1</width></LineStyle>
```

Just remember that the encoding of the four hex bytes for the color is a bit unusual:   
**Alpha, B, G, R**

So 660000FF is Red (#FF on position 4) with an alpha-transparency of about 26% (#66 on position 1).

The KML reference with all the details can be found here: 
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference

The Birdtheme Google Maps tool (your link) allows you to directly play around with the LineStyles by simply clicking the *"Style options"* button!

**EDIT:**

If you need multiple outlines around a polygon path (i.e. highway style) you can paint the same polygon multiple times with different widths and colors. Here is a rough example how this could be implemented:

```
<Style id="outerLine">
  <LineStyle><color>FF0000FF</color><width>6</width></LineStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="innerLine">
  <LineStyle><color>FFFFFFFF</color><width>3</width></LineStyle>
</Style>

<Placemark>
  <styleUrl>#outerLine</styleUrl>
  <LineString><coordinates>6.0,48.0,0  18.0,50.0,0  16.0,41.0,0</coordinates></LineString>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
  <styleUrl>#innerLine</styleUrl>
  <LineString><coordinates>6.0,48.0,0  18.0,50.0,0  16.0,41.0,0</coordinates></LineString>
</Placemark>
```

With this technique the inner line is painted on top of the outer line. Unfortunately this limits the possibilities of making the whole ensemble semi-transparent: If you make the inner line semi-transparent it will not only show the background but also the color of the outer line shining through.

Comment: I understan but is it possible to add like a line within a line? i want like a solid line and an opaque line thicker than it

Comment: See my edit above!
(sorry for the delay - I was on vacation)